# Simplify $\frac {\sec^2\theta - \cos^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

> My question is to simplify:$$\frac {\sec^2\theta - \cos^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}$$

---

My workings:

$$\frac {\sec^2\theta - \cos^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}=\frac {\frac {1}{\cos^2\theta}- \cos^2\theta} {\tan^2\theta}$$

Then I am unable to continue, can someone please show me some working outs? Thank you.

Comment: $$\dfrac{1}{\cos^2t}-\cos^2t=\dfrac{1-\cos^4t}{\cos^2t}=\dfrac{(1-\cos^2t)(1+\cos^2t)}{\cos^2t}=\dfrac{(\sin^2t)(1+\cos^2t)}{\cos^2t}=\tan^2t(1+\cos^2t)$$

Comment: $\dfrac{1/c^2-c^2}{s^2/c^2}=\dfrac{1-c^4}{s^2}=1+c^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\sec^2 \theta-\cos^2 \theta}{\tan^2 \theta}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2 \theta}-\cos^2 \theta}{\tan^2 \theta}$$

From here, use the common denominator $\cos^2 \theta$.

$$=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2 \theta}-\frac{\cos^4 \theta}{cos^2 \theta}}{\tan^2 \theta}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{1-\cos^4 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}}{\tan^2 \theta} = \frac{\frac{(1-\cos^2 \theta)(1+\cos^2 \theta)}{\cos^2 \theta}}{\tan^2 \theta} = \frac{\frac{(1-\cos^2 \theta)(1+\cos^2 \theta)}{\cos^2 \theta}}{\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}} = \frac{{(1-\cos^2 \theta)(1+\cos^2 \theta)}}{\sin^2 \theta}$$

Recall $1-\cos^2\theta = \sin^2 \theta$.

$$= \frac{{(\sin^2 \theta)(1+\cos^2 \theta)}}{\sin^2 \theta} = 1+\cos^2 \theta$$

Comment: Wow extremely insightful solution! But i have 1 question, what is the technique when you expand the $1-cos^4\theta$

Comment: You mean when I factored it to get $(1-\cos^2 \theta)(1-\sin^2 \theta)$? If so, that is simply using the difference of squares. It is helpful to remember that $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: So i view $b$ as $cos^2\theta$ in this case? And does this apply in every cases?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Of course, as gimusi said, there are many ways (which are essentially equivalent) to simplify trig expressions since there are many definitions and base identities which lead to the same answer. It's good to use whatever way you find simplest.

Answer (score 3):

For $\cos \theta \neq 0$ we have

$$\frac {\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\cdot \frac {\frac {1}{\cos^2\theta}- \cos^2\theta} {\tan^2\theta}=\frac{1-\cos^4 \theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\frac{(1-\cos^2 \theta)(1+\cos^2 \theta)}{1-\cos^2 \theta}=1+\cos^2 \theta$$

Comment: Hey thanks! but why did you times $\frac {cos^2\theta}{cos^2\theta}$ to the equation, how does it works and can you do that? Also can i apply your technique in all cases?

Comment: @Tfue We can do that since it is equal to 1 and for the definition of the expression we are assuming $\cos \theta \neq 0$.

Comment: You can divide/multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\cos \theta$ to rewrite the expression in a form that can be simplified more easily. (Essentially, you're multiplying/dividing by $1$, so it is equivalent to the original expression.)

Comment: @Tfue Of course we can proceed in many others equivalent ways, for example $$\frac {\frac {1}{\cos^2\theta}- \cos^2\theta} {\tan^2\theta}=\frac {\frac {1}{\cos^2\theta}- \cos^2\theta} {\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}=\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\left(\frac {1}{\cos^2\theta}- \cos^2\theta\right)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed solution.
**Move on!**
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{\sec^2\theta-\cos^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta}&=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}-\cos^2\theta}{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}\tag{1}\label{ko-eq1}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1-\cos^4\theta}{\cancel{\cos^2\theta}}}{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cancel{\cos^2\theta}}}\tag{2}\label{ko-eq2}\\
&=\frac{1-\cos^4\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\tag{3}\label{ko-eq3}\\
&=\frac{\cancel{\left(1-\cos^2\theta\right)}\left(1+\cos^2\theta\right)}{\cancel{1-\cos^2\theta}}\tag{4}\label{ko-eq4}\\
&=1+\cos^2\theta\tag{5}\label{ko-eq5}
\end{align}$$
\eqref{ko-eq1} Expand $\sec^2\theta$ as $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$ and $\tan^2\theta$ as $\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$.
\eqref{ko-eq2} Get a common denominator of $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}-\cos^2\theta$ and cancel both $\cos^2\theta$. The expression $\frac{\frac{1-\cos^4\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}$ is equal to $\frac{1-\cos^4\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\cdot\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$.
\eqref{ko-eq3} After cancelling both $\cos^2\theta$.
\eqref{ko-eq4} Expand $1-\cos^4\theta$ as $\left(1-\cos^2\theta\right)\left(1+\cos^2\theta\right)$, change $\sin^2\theta$ as $1-\cos^2\theta$ and cancel the same terms on numerator and denominator.
\eqref{ko-eq5} Final result.
I hope this helps.